# Let $G=(V,E)$ be a undirected graph, $K\subseteq E$ be a cycle in $G$ and $C\subseteq E$ be a cut in $G$. Is $|K\cap C|$ always even?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a undirected graph, $K\subseteq E$ be a cycle in $G$ and $C\subseteq E$ be a cut in $G$. Is $|K\cap C|$ always even?. Intuitively I would say yes, but how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. That's the way to reason.
Let $S',T'$ be a cut-set of the cut $C$ in $G$.
It is easy to see that $S=S'\cap V(K)$ and $T=T'\cap V(K)$ a cut-set of $C$ in $K$.
If $S=\varnothing$ or $T=\varnothing$, then $|K\cap C|=0$ and so is even.
Let $S\neq\varnothing$ and $T\neq\varnothing$.

Let's fix on the $K$ cycle some direction of traversal. Then by traversing the cycle in this direction we will meet consecutively vertices from $T$ and $S$:
$$
T_1S_1T_2S_2\ldots T_kS_k,
$$
where $\cup S_i=S$, $\cup T_i=T$.
Each edge at the junction of $S_i$, $T_j$ belongs to $C$.
It follows that exactly $2k$ edges of the cycle $K$ must lie in $C$.